# Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN, 0)"

Tags: html, d3.js, c3.js

When displaying the following chart (which is still working). I get the following error:

```
Error: <g> attribute transform: Expected number, "translate(NaN, 0)".
```

My code is the following:

```
var Attempts = c3.generate({
  bindto: '#attempts',
  data: {
      url: 'attempts.csv',
      x:"index",
      type: 'donut',
      onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
      onmouseover: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseover", d, i); },
      onmouseout: function (d, i) { console.log("onmouseout", d, i); }
  },
  donut: {
    label: {
      format: function (value) { return value; }
    }
  }
});
```

attempts.csv is:

```
index,Basic Mechanics,Basic Thermodynamics,Calculus I,Calculus II,Chemistry I,Chemistry II,Engineering Drawing,Fundamentals of Informatics,Geometry,Linear Algebra
ATTEMPTS,1.416,1.404,1.421,1.347,1.305,1.246,1.261,1.456,1.325,1.385
```

Complete error is:

```
c3_chart_internal_fn.convertUrlToData
c3_chart_internal_fn.init
Chart
c3.generate
(anonymous)
```

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, is it trying to parse this first entry (`ATTEMPTS`) as a number or is that part of the headers and formatted incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Phix I also thought of removing that first column, but then there is not value x and I dont know why it didnt work. But if you could tell me how to avoid passing x value to the donut chart then I can remove the first column (containing index) and see if the error disappears

Comment: I think C3js expects your rows and columns the other way around (titles at the top, each data point on each line)

Comment: @WesLord Thanks for helping! But the chart is displayed properly so I do not understand how I get the error and then the chart is fine...

Comment: I just downloaded the latest version of C3js (0.6.1) and D3 (5.4.0) and set up a simple project with your code and your CSV file, and it works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox on MacOS, with no errors in the dev console.

Answer (score 0):

This error, if the "js" code exist

```
$('#test').vectorMap();
```

and "html" code is not exist seen.

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer, despite my huge efforts I couldn't understand what you were trying to say.